# How can I fake a multi-item $pop in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Quick question from someone new to Mongo.

I have a collection of documents that (simplified) look like this:

```
{"_id":<objectID>, "name":"fakeName", "seeds":[1231,2341,0842,1341,3451, ...]}
```

What I really need is a $pop that pops 2 or 3 items off my list of seeds, but $pop currently only works for [one](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) item, so I'm trying to look for another way to accomplish the same thing.

The first thing I looked at was doing $push/$each/$slice with an empty "each", like:

```
update: { $push: { order: { $each: [ ], $slice: ?}}}
```

The problem here is that I don't know exactly how long I want my new slice to be (I want it to be "current size - number of seeds I popped"). If the $slice modifier worked like the $slice projection, this would be easy, I could just do $slice: [ #of seeds, ], but it doesn't so that doesn't work.

The next thing I looked at was getting the side of the array and using that as an input to $slice, like:

```
update: { $push: { seeds: { $each: [ ], $slice: {$subtract: [{$size:"$seeds"}, <number of seeds to pop>]}}}}
```

But Mongo tells me "value for $slice must be numeric value and not an Object", so apparently the result of $subtract is an Object not a number.

Then I tried to see if I could "remove" items from the array based on an empty query with a $limit, but apparently limit gets applied later in the pipeline, so I couldn't manage to make that work.

Any other suggestions, or am I out of luck and need to go back to the drawing board?

Thanks so much for help/input.

Comment: Are you doing an update or running an aggregation pipeline? They are mutually exclusive. If it's an aggregation pipeline, what's the final output that you are looking for, both conceptually and exemplified as an output document?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not presently have any method of referencing the existing values of fields in a singular update statement. The only exceptions are operators such as `$inc` an `$mul` which can act on the present value and alter it according to a set rule.

This is in part due to the compatibility of the "phrasing" of operations to act over multiple documents, whether that is the case or not. But what you are asking for is some "variable" operation that allows the "length" of an array to be tested and used as in "input parameter" to another method. This is not supported.

So the best you can do is read the document content and test the length of the array in code, then perform the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) update as you first surmized, or alternately you could use the aggregation framework to work out the "possible lengths" of arrays ( assuming a lot of duplication ) and then work on "multi" updates for those documents that match the conditions, of course assuming that you want to do this over more than a single document.

First form:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    if ( doc.order.length > 2 ) {
        bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id })
            .updateOne({ 
                "$push": {
                    "order": { "$each": [], "$slice": doc.order.length - 2 }
                }
            });
        count ++;
    }

    if ( (count % 1000) == 0 && ( count > 1 ) ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

Second form:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": { "$size": "$order" } }},
    { "$match": { "$_id": { "$gt": 2 } }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {

   bulk.find({ "order": { "$size": doc._id } })
       .update(
            "$push": {
                "order": { "$each": [], "$slice": doc._id - 2 }
            }
        });
        count ++;

   if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
       bulk.execute();
       bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
   }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

Noting that in both cases there is some logic to consider the length of the arrays in order not to "empty" them, or produce an undesired `$slice` operation.

Another possibly alternative is to use the projection form of [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) in the query to get the last `n` elements and then [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) the matching elements from the array. Of course the identifier used for such an operation would have to be "unique", but it is a valid case where uniqueness is assured.

So whatever your case, you cannot do this in a singular update statement without having some prior knowledge of the current state of the document to be modified. The different listings though give you ways to approach "emulating" this, albeit not in a single statement.